# Filling vector with a single char*, pointing to the base of a char* array in C

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Assuming that I have a `char*` of the base of a `char*[]`. I know that every `char*` in the array is null-terminated, and the last entry is NULL.

```
char* args[] = {"foo", "bar", NULL};
```

If I cast this to a `char*`, I should get the start address of `"foo"`.

```
char* p = (char*)args;
```

Now, I would like to fill a vector of `char*`, only with the `char* p` variable. Is this possible?

My code:

```
vector<char*> arguments;
bool null_terminated = true;
while(p!=NULL)
{
  if (null_terminated)
  {
    arguments.push_back((char *) p);
    null_terminated = false;
  }
  if ((*(char*)p) == '\0')
    null_terminated = true;
  p++;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Is there a different solution?

Comment: Why not use `char** p`?

Comment: "I should get the start address of `"foo"`" No, you shouldn't. Now `p` points at the pointer to `"foo"` (`args[0]`), not `"foo"`.

Comment: @MikeCAT oh you mean I should cast, args to a `char**` instead of a `char*`?

Comment: No. I mean the type of `p` should be `char**` and then no casting will be required.

Comment: @MikeCAT Oh I understand, ty so much.

Comment: Also it seems unclear what you want to do with the vector. What should the vector contain after the operation?

Comment: in this case, "foo" and "bar"

Comment: Then I think you should simply do `for(char** p = args; *p != NULL; p++) arguments.push_back(*p);`. This looks like [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to use `char* p`?

Comment: @MikeCAT oh wow nice, didn't think of this being a possibility, probably due to my limited knowledge to C and pointers. yep seems to be the XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think filling the vector with `char* p` is possible using things like `reinterpret_cast`, but it will be tricky, dangerous, and not guaranteed. I won't recommend this.

Instead of this, to fill the vector with non-null elements of `args`, I think you should use a pointer to point at the elements of the array `char** p` and use that to traverse the array.

It will be like this:

```
for(char** p = args; *p != NULL; p++) {
    arguments.push_back(*p);
}
```

Note that `p` points at the elements and the dereferenced `*p` will be the elements.